# Unable to connect to a Web Service in Xamarin.Android(C#)

Tags: c#, android, web-services

I use real Android device connected to the PC via USB cable.I've added the webreference in the Xamarin.Android App, then I instantiate it in the code like that:

```
WebReference.WebServiceEmp service = new WebReference.WebServiceEmp();
var data = service.HelloWorld();
```

But it throws:

```
System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection timed out)
```

When I add the service reference in Console Application instantiateing it like that:

```
ServiceReference1.WebServiceEmpSoapClient 
service= new ServiceReference1.WebServiceEmpSoapClient();
DataTable data = service.Add();
```

It works fine. Why it doesn't work in Xamarin Android app? (I added the reference url like that:
http://(myIp):8092/WebServiceEmp.asmx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did You Carry out All the steps Given in the link below? [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/)

I mean to say Did You Register your IP?